# Ubuntu VPN Using Sonicwall

Tags: vpn

The **only** thing keeping me from blowing away the crappy Vista install on my Toshiba laptop and going pure Ubuntu is the fact that I need to VPN to work and they use Sonicwall. Due to some proprietary voodoo used by that particular firewall setup on  my work's end, I have to use the Sonicwall client which only runs on Windows.

Has anyone found a way to VPN to a sonicwall connection from Ubuntu?

Comment: maybe http://www.sonicwall.com/downloads/SonicOS_Enhanced_to_Openswan_Using_GroupVPN_with_XAUTH.pdf

Answer (score 6):

1. Go to https://sslvpn.demo.sonicwall.com/cgi-bin/welcome  log in with
   `demo/password`
2. Click on NetExtender icon: this will download a tar.gz with the
   client.
3. (Optional) `sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/libssl.so.6`
4. (Optional) `sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.6`
5. Untar the client, make install script executable (chmod u+x) and launch install

**NB**: When executing the installation script, do not allow root access

`sudo ./install`

```
--- Dell SonicWALL NetExtender 7.5.761 Installer ---
Checking library dependencies...
Checking pppd...
Do you want non-root users to be able to run NetExtender?
    If so, I can set pppd to run as root, but this could be
    considered a security risk.

Set pppd to run as root [y/N]? N
You have chosen NOT to allow non-root users to run NetExtender.
Copying files...

------------------------ INSTALLATION SUCCESSFUL -----------------------
```

To launch NetExtender, do one of the following:

1. Click the NetExtender icon under the Applications menu
    (look under the 'Internet' or 'Network' category)
    or
2. Type `netExtenderGui`

Solution tested from Ubuntu 13 to 18.04.

Comment: For 14.04, steps 3 and 4 above were not needed. Just download and run the installer.

Comment: This is only for SSL VPN

Comment: Confirm works great, I confirm steps 3 and 4 are not needed on 18.04.  Also need to ensure java is installed if you plan to use the GUI

Comment: NexExtender does not support pre-shared keys.

Answer (score 4):

not necessarily the best source, but it seems you can do this using OpenSwan VPN under linux.

It's not a trivial setup of clicking a few checkboxes, but it seems doable.

http://www.pelagodesign.com/blog/2009/05/18/ubuntu-linux-how-to-setup-a-vpn-connection-to-a-sonicwall-router-using-openswan-and-pre-shared-keys-psk/

OR

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=527423

between those 2 articles you should be able to figure something out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a Sonicwall NetExtender client that is available for download from sonicwalls website.  I use it all the time.  Once installed just type netExtender (case sensitive) from the command line and you will be prompted for your creds.

Answer (score 0):

I too, the same stage now. I did'nt tried OpenSwan VPN. How ever net extender won't help in my case. 
As per my knowledge we have to configure NetExtender in sonicwall device in-order to use NetExtender client

Answer (score 0):

There is an official knowledge base article from SonicWall [here](https://www.sonicwall.com/support/knowledge-base/how-do-i-download-and-install-netextender-on-linux/180105195559153/) that goes through the steps for Linux installation. They discuss both GUI and command line usage of the `netExtender` program once installed. The later is nice because you won't have to install additional Java dependencies for the GUI

The only inaccuracy I noticed in the article is that there is no "Refine by" button to select for NetExtender. Instead, you need to click the dropdown with "Global Vpn Client (32-Bit)"